# Method to print the list of all the factors of a number with return type int

Tags: java

I am a beginner in coding. Right now I am experimenting with different return data types.

Here I am trying to make a method which prints a list of factors of the parsed number but this code does not seems to work. The method is working for void return type (by adding `System.out.println()`). Can anyone help?

```
    public static int printFactorsInt(int number) {

    if (number < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    int factor = 0;

    for (int i =1 ; i <= number; i++) {

        if ((number % i) == 0) {
            factor = i;
        }
    }

    return factor;
}
```

Comment: This would just return a single factor. (that too the number itself.) Is that what you're trying?

Comment: @nullpointer it will return input until it is less then `1`, in this case will return `-1`

Comment: Your code returns only the last factor, you need to change your code to return a list of integers and your int factor should also be a list of integers.

Comment: @nullpointer Actually I want a list  of integers.

Comment: For every factor you find you can get a second factor for free.  If f is a factor, then num / f is also a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean all factors for a number? If yes then you can use a `list` to capture the numbers that are factors and then return that `list`.

```
public static List<Integer> printFactorsInt(int number) {
    List<Integer> listOfFactors = new ArrayList<>(); 

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        if ((number % i) == 0) {
            listOfFactors.add(i);
        }
    }
    return listOfFactors;
}
```

The problem with your code was that you were returning only 1 number which happened to be the last factor.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a beginner in Java and have not yet learned about the List return type.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess all you need to do is just print the value of `i` instead of using the list inside the `if`.

Answer (score 4):

To print all the factors of a number you should also have a System.out.print(factor + " "); in the for loop.

```
public static int printFactorsInt(int number) {

    if (number < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    int factor = 0;

    for (int i =1 ; i <= number; i++) {

        if ((number % i) == 0) {
            factor = i;
            System.out.print(factor + " ");
        }
    }

    return factor;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the return type in this method?

Comment: The for loop is working fine now. However the `return factor;` is adding an extra factor, which is same as the last one.

Comment: @NicholasK I have run this method successfully with void return type. I was just wondering how to run it with an int return type. Its basically for my own satisfaction.